# Only one label appearing on a BarChart created with Charts

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I want to create a BarChart with the Charts library. Everything is working good except the labels on the x axis. Only the first label "Jan" is appearing on the line. This is my code

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        doBarChart()
    }

    func doBarChart(){


        barChartView.drawBarShadowEnabled = false
        barChartView.drawValueAboveBarEnabled = true
        barChartView.chartDescription?.enabled = false

        barChartView.maxVisibleCount = 60

        let xAxis  = barChartView.xAxis
        xAxis.axisLineColor = UIColor.black
        xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
        xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = true
        xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
        xAxis.granularity = 1.0
        xAxis.labelCount = 1
       // xAxis.setLabelCount(7, force: true)
        let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul",]

        xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values:months)
        //Also, you probably want to add:



        let leftAxis = barChartView.leftAxis;
        leftAxis.enabled = false
        leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false;
        leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false;
        leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0; // this replaces startAtZero = YES

        let rightAxis = barChartView.rightAxis
        rightAxis.enabled = false;

        rightAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = true;
        rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false;
        rightAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0; // this replaces startAtZero = YES

        let l = barChartView.legend
        l.enabled =  false

        barChartView.fitBars = true;
        barChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 0.2, yAxisDuration: 1.0, easingOptionX: .easeInExpo, easingOptionY: .easeInExpo)

        setDataCount(count: 7, range: 50)

    }


    func setDataCount(count: Int, range: Double){

        let barWidth = 7.0
        let spaceForBar =  10.0

        var yVals = [BarChartDataEntry]()


        yVals.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(0) * spaceForBar, y: 44.5))
        yVals.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(1) * spaceForBar, y: 78.1))
        yVals.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(2) * spaceForBar, y: 50.3))
        yVals.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(3) * spaceForBar, y: 56.6))
        yVals.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(4) * spaceForBar, y: 20.5))
        yVals.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(5) * spaceForBar, y: 44.3))
        yVals.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(6) * spaceForBar, y: 54.4))

        var set1 : BarChartDataSet!


        if let count = barChartView.data?.dataSetCount, count > 0{
            set1 = barChartView.data?.dataSets[0] as! BarChartDataSet
            set1.values = yVals
            set1.colors = [UIColor.black,UIColor.orange,UIColor.red,UIColor.green,UIColor.yellow,UIColor.blue,UIColor.gray]
            barChartView.data?.notifyDataChanged()
            barChartView.notifyDataSetChanged()

        }else{
            set1 = BarChartDataSet(values: yVals, label: "DataSet")
            set1.colors = [UIColor.black,UIColor.orange,UIColor.red,UIColor.green,UIColor.yellow,UIColor.blue,UIColor.gray]


            var dataSets = [BarChartDataSet]()
            dataSets.append(set1)

            let data = BarChartData(dataSets: dataSets)


            data.barWidth =  barWidth;

            barChartView.data = data

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Add the following delegate method of "IAxisValueFormatter"

And assign these delegate.

class xyz :  IAxisValueFormatter{

weak var axisFormatDelegate: IAxisValueFormatter?

//add these line in the func...

func doBarChart{
  let xAxisValue = lineChartView.xAxis
        xAxisValue.valueFormatter = axisFormatDelegate
        lineChartView.xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
        lineChartView.xAxis.granularity = 1.0
}

//add these method..

 func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        return yvlaues[Int(value) % yvlaues.count]
  }
}
```